# How to specify an unique fact in prolog?

Tags: prolog, unique

I want to specify a comment of a person about a thing if is positive or negative but can't be both.

**I want to put into my file a general rule and these facts:**

```
:-comment(Person, Thing, B), comment(Person, Thing, OtherB), B \=OtherB.
comment(person, book, positive).
comment(person, book, negative).
```

And when I try to make a Query I will receive an error, or something telling me something is contradictory.

**Of course are valid the follows facts:**

```
comment(person, book, positive).
comment(person, icecream, negativa).
```

Comment: *when* you want to enforce the rule ? `comment(P,O,C), comment(P,O,D), C\=D, throw(invalid_comment).`

Comment: @CapelliC it doesn't work how I expected. I try to put it in a file so, it will be contradictory after I load it in the Console. But it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your file a **checkContradictory** (at least in ***gnuprolog***) in the following way:

**yourfile.lp**

```
comment(person, book, positive).
comment(person, book, negative).

checkContradictory:- checkCommentContradiction, ... others checking predicates

checkCommentContradiction:-comment(Person, Thing, positive),
            comment(Person, Thing, negative),throw(contradiction_with_comments).
```

So if you want to check your file before the query, just execute your **checkContradictory** or if you have an main predicate, just add **checkContradictory** like requirement.

**Important** if you need to have a yes free of error and an Exception when there are a contradiction you need to add an findall:

**yourfile.lp**

```
comment(person, book, positive).
comment(person, book, negative).

checkFreeOfContradictory:- checkAllCommentsContradictions.

checkAllCommentsContradictions:-findall(X,checkCommentContradiction,R).

checkCommentContradiction:-comment(Person, Thing, B1),
            comment(Person, Thing, B2),
            (B1==B2->true;throw(contradiction_with_comments)).
```

Mainly because *the same fact will unify with **comment(Person, thing, B1)** and **comment(Person, Thing, B2)***.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know how to write into my KB. :)  And yes, I realize that ;)

Answer (score 0):

will it be easier if you restructure your predicates?
replacing one predicate by two in such a way:

```
positive_comment(Person,Book).
negative_comment(Person,Book).
```

then use some like

```
positive_comment(Person,Book):-
negative_comment(Person,Book),
throw_some_error,
false.
negative_comment(Person,Book):-
positive_comment(Person,Book),
throw_some_error,
false.
```

or better use separate checker:

```
check_comments_consistency(Person,Book):-
  positive_comment(Person,Book),
  negative_comment(Person,Book),
  throw_some_error.
```

... or something like that.

you get the idea?

Comment: Yes, I do. But what if I want to set a third opinion (e.g: indecisive). And if I'm trying to do the same with other predicates, it will be NumberOfPredicates*PossiblesValues

Comment: you will have no more than log2(N) simple predicates representing complex predicate (N is number of distinct opinions). think about that as encoding of path in some decision tree.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram any multivalued complex logic can be encoded manually in boolean logic. and simplified formally after that.

Comment: read something about 3- or 4-valued logic. solution of you fact-consistency problem is just to implement truth tables for those multivalued logic. programmaticaly implement reactions on all possible cases and do not forget any of it. draw vienne digram with number of rings equal to number of opinion kinds. if there is two - positive/negative then you have 4 cases. pos/neg/unknown/conflicting.

Comment: and i must warn you. if you use 3-arg comment(P,B,value) encoding then you inevitable get all problems related with conflicting or undefined values. requires that you manually implement proper reaction on such multivalued logic in you knowledge-base engine and do it right.

Comment: with two predicates (positive/negative) you can represent 4 states of knowledge about something: positive, negative, unknown_yet, impossible. in 60-x there even was 3-ary computer Setun...